# GraphQL - When to use a resolver or an argument with recursive and normalized data?

Tags: graphql

I'm working with a very large normalized and recursive object.  I want to get the list of all recursive items.  Should I use an argument or a custom resolver?

My object looks like:

```js
{
  products: [{
    product_id: "car",
    bundle_id: 5
  },{
    product_id: "door"
    bundle_id: 6
  },
  { product_id: "wheel" },
  { product_id: "metal" },
  { product_id: "glass" }],

  bundles: [{
    bundle_id: 5,
    options: [{product_id: "door"},{product_id: "wheel"}]
  },
  {
    bundle_id: 6,
    options: [{product_id: "metal"},{product_id: "glass"}]
  }]

}
```

You might notice that "car" is a `bundle` that has a `door` and a `wheel`.  "door" is also a `bundle` that has `metal` and `glass`.  This structure could recurse indefinitely. That is, a bundle could have infinitely more bundle products underneath it.

I want to get a list of all products for a bundle (example: "car").  What is the best approach?

I see two options.

First Option - use a custom resolver, for example `child_products` that would recurse and resolve to a flat array of all children:

```
products(product_id: "car") {
  product_id
  bundle {
    options {
      product_id
    }
  }
  child_products {
    product_id
    bundle {
      options {
        product_id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second Option - use an argument that specifies including all children:

```
products(product_id: "car", include_children: true) {
  product_id
  bundle {
    options {
      product_id
    }
  }
}
```

I'm going to build a JS library that can take the array of products and options and build the nested structure. Please let me know what you think is the right way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need an argument like `include_children` because a client's query will be sufficient to determine whether to include the nodes or not -- if a client doesn't need the nodes, it can simply omit the appropriate field.

Based on the provided JSON object, I would expect a schema that looks something like this:

```
type Query {
  product(id: ID!): Product
}

type Product {
  id: ID!
  bundle: Bundle
}

type Bundle {
  id: ID!
  options: [Product!]!
}
```

which would let you make a query like:

```
query {
  product(id: "car") {
    id
    bundle {
      options {
        id
        bundle {
          id
          # and so on...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The actual depth of this query would be left up to the client's needs. Recursive type definitions like this do present a possible attack vector and so you should also look into using a library like [graphql-depth-limit](https://github.com/stems/graphql-depth-limit) or [graphql-query-complexity](https://github.com/slicknode/graphql-query-complexity).

Comment: Thanks! Most clients will need to get the full depth.  But that depth can change depending on the bundle.  Despite this, you'd still recommend just requesting some "reasonable maximum" amount ... say a depth of 10?  

Also, the relationship between a product and its sub-products is not as simple as described above.  The options values look more like a selector: `{type: "glass", weight: {gt: 5}}`, would you make a resolver like `product_options` and then use this 10 levels deep?

Comment: I suppose there's no room here for infinite recursion since eventually we would hit a product without a bundle, so you may not have to necessarily limit the depth. But yes, you may need to figure out what the max depth looks like and create the request based on that.

Comment: In that case, `options` can be some other intermediate type like `BundleOption` that would then have a `product` field.